# Linux file recovery after unexpected shutdown

Tags: linux, data-recovery, shutdown, file-recovery, nano

Yesterday, I was using a nano file to take important notes relating to university work. I had not saved the file at any point that day, and was actively taking notes throughout the day. Towards the end of the day, my laptop ran out of power and shut down before I saved (yes I know, silly of me to not save when my laptop was on low power).
Lets say the directory the file was being edited in was
`~/Documents/uni/notes.txt`

After rebooting my laptop, the file is not still open in my terminal, furthermore, there is no .save file that I was hoping nano may have created in such an event. I've attempted to find a .save file both in the directories that I thought it might be in, and in my entire system by running the following commands:
`sudo find  /  -mtime -1 -print | egrep -i '\.save$|\.save\.[1-90]*$'`
as well as
`sudo find / "*.save"` and `sudo find / "notes.*"`.
No luck.

Is there any way that I may be able to recover the file? Is it possible that it may still be held in memory or swap space? If so, how might I go about checking if it can be found in memory? I am running Arch Linux (systemd).

Comment: 1. Your OS should be set to suspend on low power, not shutdown. This would have given you plenty (OK, some) time to plug the power supply and avoid the disaster. 2. Simple text editors typically don't save drafts, unlike office suites. 3. Sorry, it's gone.

Comment: Thank you, I will set my computer to suspend rather than shutdown at low-power, as well as not use nano for important notes in the future.

Comment: Even if it is possible to recover, it's much simplier for you to just recreate the notes TBH, unless you don't remember them. `nano` has emergency autosave mechanisms BTW, just not for the lack of power ofc as that can't be detected. See https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nano.1.html But I'd never use a tool like that for notes - reliable cloud-based solutions like Google Keep or Evernote or any of a bunch of alternatives are the way to go if the notes are in fact important.

Comment: BTW, running a battery below ~10% *greatly* shortens its life. Suspend (Sleep) does *not* completely shut the machine, just reduces power, and eventually will completely deplete the battery. To force saving all files when power is too low, use hibernation, if available (admittedly, many Linux distros do not enable hibernate by default).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you are more likely asking about `nano`'s specific behavior when it is killed in a shutdown.

PS: You did not describe how your laptop shutdown: Was it an OS shutdown or a brutal out-of-power? Latter absolutely won't help. Even in former case, it depends on what signal the OS sends to processes. I did this reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499764/544770 and find that usually Linux should send SIGTERM first before sending SIGKILL.

I do understand that it saves `.save` files in certain signals: https://askubuntu.com/a/601989/1640619. It does mention SIGTERM. However, it did not work in your case.

Your file is gone for this time. For future, consider using an editor that periodically save, instead of trying to save before it dies.

One other thing you can try is to reproduce this behavior by working on some file in nano then directly run `sudo poweroff` from a terminal/TTY, and see if it saves anything. If it does save a `nano.save`, then in the previous run your laptop might have shutdown non-elegantly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My laptop ran out of power and forcibly shutdown. I would say "brutal out-of-power" describes what occurred best. I'm coming to terms with not having the file anymore, and I will be more cautious in the future to use something that makes regular backups, as well as change the behavior of my laptop to suspend rather than shutting down when power is critically low. I think the shutdown was far from "elegant" because when my laptop rebooted, I saw in the boot sequence that it repaired damage to the drive.

Comment: @LilyD.D. Sounds like right. Sorry for your loss :-( It is not possible for process to do anything that it usually does "before death", if the shutdown was brutal. It is like when you are working on a desktop, then someone pulled out your power cord. In this way, we will have to need something that saves periodically.